# regex result filter in python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a program with regexes, I have to filter them but I can't find out how. I want to match every red,xxxx or xxxx,red expression in my string and put the colors xxxx into a group. Here is my code:

```
string = "blue,red   red,yellow   blue,yellow   red,green   purple red, ..."
regex = re.compile('(?:red,(?P<redfirst>\w+)|(?P<othercolorfirst>\w+),red)')
```

Then I write:

```
for match in regex.finditer(string):
    if match.group('redfirst')!= "None":
        print(match.group("redfirst"))
```

But I still obtain printing like:

```
None
yellow
green
None
```

I dont want the 'None' results to appear, I have to skip them in an smart way if possible.
Thanks for help!

**EDIT** None without quotes doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile('(?:red,(?P<redfirst>\w+)|(?P<othercolorfirst>\w+),red)')

>>> string = "blue,red   red,yellow   blue,yellow   red,green   purple red, ..."

>>> for matches in regex.finditer(string):
...     if matches.group('redfirst'):
...         print matches.group('redfirst')
...
yellow
green
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The result when nothing matches isn't `"None"` (the string), it's `None` (the singleton object). And while simply stripping the quotes around `None` in your condition works, it's preferred to use `... is None` for numerous reasons, the most important being that it's [in the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (hey, consistency wins - usually) and that it doesn't break on a badly-written `__eq__` (not an issue here and more of a paranoia anyway, but since there are no downsides, why not?).

Comment: bad answer... I check my facts before posting, None without quotes doesn't work for me

Comment: @Kingpin: That's a strong claim, you'll have to support it with code. `None` is a builtin and globally available, and `group` is [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) to return `None` when the group didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
>>> redfirst, othercolorfirst = zip(*(m.groups() for m in regex.finditer(string)))
>>> redfirst
(None, 'yellow', 'green')
>>> othercolorfirst
('blue', None, None)
>>> filter(None, redfirst)
('yellow', 'green')
>>> filter(None, othercolorfirst)
('blue',)
>>> print "\n".join(filter(None, redfirst))
yellow
green
```